# Indentation in numbered examples

Tags: indentation, linguex

The text of an example numbered with two digit number seems to be indented further then the text of examples numbered with single digit numbers (as in the example below). Can I control for this throughout the document (not just for each particular example separately)?

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
   \usepackage[american]{babel}
   \usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(10)}}` to your preamble after loading `linguex` (`(10)` representing the width of your widest label). See section "\Exlabelwidth"  of the `linguex` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
   \usepackage[american]{babel}
   \usepackage{linguex}

\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(10)}}

\begin{document}

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text

   \ex. Text


\end{document}
```